# Android bitmap colorfiltering gives different output

Tags: android, android-canvas, ondraw, colormatrix, colorfilter

I got a problem where using a ColorMatrixColorFilter gives different outputs.
I got this picture:
[image]

It has white, red, and transparent parts.
I have a view, overriding the onDraw(Canvas) method, where i draw this picture.

```
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(r, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(r, r.getWidth(), 0, blank);
        canvas.drawBitmap(r, r.getWidth() * 2, 0, identity);//darker why?
        canvas.drawBitmap(identityfiltered, r.getWidth() * 3, 0, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(identityfiltered, r.getWidth() * 4, 0, blank);
        canvas.drawBitmap(identityfiltered, r.getWidth() * 5, 0, identity);//darker why?
    }
```

The other variables explained:

```
Paint blank = new Paint(); //blank paint

ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(new float[] { 
                    1, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, // red
                    0, 1f, 0f, 0f, 0f, // green
                    0, 0f, 1f, 0f, 0f, // blue
                    0, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f, // alpha
            });
Paint identity = new Paint();
identity.setColorFilter(filter); //the paint with identity filter

Bitmap r = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.my_drawable);// my drawable

Bitmap identityfiltered = Bitmap.createBitmap(r.getWidth(), r.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888); //new bitmap with the same width height as my drawable, Bitmap r is drawn on this with the identity filter
Canvas c = new Canvas(identityfiltered);
c.drawBitmap(r, 0, 0, identity);
```

And the given output is:

[image]

As you can see the 3rd and 6th drawn bitmap is darker, that is when I directly draw to then View's canvas with the colorfilter. The question is why? Shouldn't it be the same, since the same filter is applied?

Update: I've been testing around, **seems like it has something to do with semi-transparent** images. I tried to copy fully opaque images and that went fine in all 6 cases.

But back to my image, I even tried with the identity matrix given by the API.

```
The new ColorMatrix() constructor comes with identity matrix initialized.
```

But had the same result.